# Function setting all $_COOKIE variables in $_SESSION doesn't work

Tags: php, global-variables

```
function cookiesToSession()
    {
        foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value)
        {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
```

Hi everyone, the above code doesn't work. The goal was to have for any $_COOKIE['var'] an automatic setting of $_SESSION['var'].

Any ideas about what went wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you call `session_start()` prior to this function? Did you remember to call this function? (I've done that before: write a function and then forget to actually call it!).

If neither of those are the issue, check that session saving is properly configured - does the savepath exist? Is the session cookie domain/path valid? That sort of thing.

Comment: Yep, session_start() is good and I've called the function as well. I think the problem is in the function's syntax itself.

Comment: If that were the case you'd be getting syntax errors. I don't see anything wrong with the function itself, which is why I suggested such things as the session configuration.

Comment: Sessions and cookies seem properly configured. Maybe I've made a mistake in variable scope ?

Comment: Nope, `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIE` are superglobals so you never need to worry about their scope. What do you get if you call `var_dump($_COOKIE,$_SESSION);` immediately after calling `cookiesToSession()`?